# Proposition 9 on chapter 3 of Royden and Fitzpatrick's Real Analysis

Tags: real-analysis

At some point in the proof of proposition 9, the book says: "Observe that for a point $x\in E$, since $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}f_n(x)=f(x)$: $f(x)<c \iff$ $(\exists n,k \in \mathbb{N}) $ $(\forall j\geq k)$ $(f_j(x)<c-\frac{1}{n})$.

I'm not sure why this is true, I reckon the authors used the archimedean property and the definition of pointwise convergence for the logical equivalence above, but I'm getting different inequalities. This is what I get given $x\in E$: $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}f_n(x)=f(x) \iff (\forall \varepsilon>0) (\exists k\in \mathbb{N})(\forall j\geq k)(|f_j(x)-f(x)|<\varepsilon)$. Now, if $f(x)<c$, let's choose $\frac{1}{\varepsilon}>n$, and thus what we will have is $f_j(x)<c+\frac{1}{n}$.

My main question is, how did they construct $n$ in their proof above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $f(x)<c$, there is $n\in \mathbb N$ so that $f(x) + \frac 1n <c$ (this is where one uses the Archimedean property). Let $\epsilon = c-\frac 1n -f(x)$. then $\epsilon >0$ and there is $k \in \mathbb N$ so that $|f_j(x) - f(x)|<\epsilon$ for all $j\ge k$. Thus

$$\begin{split}
f_j(x) &= f_j(x) - f(x) + f(x) \\
&\le |f_j(x) - f(x)| + f(x) \\
&< c-\frac 1n - f(x) + f(x) \\
&= c-\frac 1n
\end{split}$$
for all $j\ge k$.

Comment: Argh, it's so simple. I spent almost an hour looking at it like an idiot. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If $f(x)<c$, then there exists an $n$ such that $f(x)<c-\frac{1}{n}$. Now expand $|f_j(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$ as $f(x)-\epsilon<f_j(x)<f(x)+\epsilon$.
Finally $f(x)+\epsilon<c-\frac{1}{n}+\epsilon$. So let $\epsilon<+c-\frac{1}{n}-f(x)$. This choice of epsilon clearly does the trick working backwards to get $f_j(x)<c-\frac{1}{n}$.